# Nested conditionals

Tags: conditional-content

Got my brain scratching round a wee issue here.

In short...

1. If home page, then do nothing
2. if page has a thumbnail then run code that pops the page title on top of full width thumbnail with suitable CSS
3. If no thumbnail then show normal entry title

Got so far but no further. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<header class="entry-header">
    <?php
    if ( is_front_page() ) { 
        // This is the home page and do nothing
    } else {
        // if thumbnail show it and add title

    if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
        <div class="single-featured-image">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </div>
    <?php } else {
        // if no thumbnail then just print title as usual ?>
    <div class="entry-title">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:

```
<?php
//if home, do nothing
if( ! is_home() || ! front_page() ) {

    //if has post thumbnail
    if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {        
        the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );
        echo '<h1 class="entry-title">'. get_the_title() .'</h1>';
    } else {        
        //no post thumbnail, show normal entry title
        echo '<h1 class="entry-title">'. get_the_title() .'</h1>';
    }

}
```

or, it can be done easily:

```
<?php
if( ! is_home() || ! is_front_page() ) {

    if( has_post_thumbnail() )
        the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );
    echo '<h1 class="entry-title">'. get_the_title() .'</h1>';

}
```

Comment: `is_front_page()` might be better than `is_home`, since per [Codex here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home#Blog_Posts_Index_vs._Site_Front_Page): 

`On the site front page, is_front_page() will always return TRUE, regardless of whether the site front page displays the blog posts index or a static page.

On the blog posts index, is_home() will always return TRUE, regardless of whether the blog posts index is displayed on the site front page or a separate page.`

Comment: @czerspalace thanks. `is_front_page()` added. :)

Answer (score 2):

Write it out in english and be clear about your logic, aka if you say that X should happen when Y is true, what happens if Y is false? AKA `else`. If X then Y, else Z

```
If we're on the home page,
    then do nothing
otherwise
    if the page has a thumbnail then
        run code that pops the page title on top of full width thumbnail with suitable CSS
    otherwise,
        just show normal entry title
```

Also notice the consistent indentation, keeping code indented properly is extremely important and prevents a huge raft of obvious bugs. Good editors will auto-indent for you.

Your code doesn't indent correctly, it also mixes 2 types of if statement together, `if() { }` and `if () : endif;`, resulting in `if() : }` which is a syntax error. So put your opening if statement on its own line, and the closing part on its own line so it's really obvious what's happening. A good editor will automatically write out the `{` and `}` for you, saving you the effort. If your editor doesn't do these things, you need to switch, there are numerous free editors and paid editors that will do this and more as standard